# How to add many to one relationship with model from external application in django

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

My django project uses django-helpdesk app.
This app has `Ticket` model.

My app got a `Client` model, which should have one to many relationship with ticket- so I could for example list all tickets concerning specific client.

Normally I would add `models.ForeignKey(Client)` to `Ticket`
But it's an external app and I don't want to modify it (future update problems etc.).

I wold have no problem with `ManyToMany` or `OneToOne` but don't know how to do it with `ManyToOne` (many tickets from external app to one Client from my app)

Comment: Use a helper model, that has a `OneToOne` with `Client` and a `ManyToMany` with `Ticket`

Comment: @elssar He can already define a `ManyToMany` between `Client` and `Ticket`, there is no need for a helper class in that case. I think you meant a helper class that has a `OneToOne` with **`Ticket`** and a **`OneToMany`** relation with `Client`.

Comment: related question : is there any way to create `TicketProfile` when posting new ticket without modifying `helpdesk.views`, maybe custom middleware?

Comment: @Lord_JABA Yes, you can [listen the post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/) to create `TicketProfile` when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Even more hacky solution**: You can do the following in the module level code after you `Client` class:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='tickets')
client.contribute_to_class(Ticket, name='client')
```

I haven't fully tested it (I didn't do any actual database migrations), but the correct descriptors (`ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` for `Ticket` and `ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor` for `Client`) get added to the class, and South recognizes the new fields. So far it seems to work just like a regular `ForeignKey`.

**EDIT**: Actually not even that hacky. This is exactly how Django sets up foreign keys across classes. It just reverses the process by adding the field when the reverse related class is built. It won't raise an error if any of the original fields on either model is shadowed. Just make sure you don't do that, as it could potentially break your code. Other than that, I don't think there should be any issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways to accomplish it:

**More elegant solution**: Use a `TicketProfile` class which has a one-to-one relation to `Ticket`, and put the `Client` foreign key into it.

**Hacky solution**: Use a many-to-many relation, and manually edit the automatically created table and make `ticket_id` unique.

Comment: If `TicketProfile` has a M2M with `Ticket` and  `OneToOne` relationship with `Client`, then, with one object he can replicate a `FK` from `Ticket` to `Client`, i.e. multiple tickets linked to one client.

Comment: Then you can theoretically create two separate `TicketProfile`s for the same ticket and link each one to different `Client`s. What you are replicating is actually a M2M relation between Client and Ticket.

Comment: ah! hadn't thought about that.